# What does CreateML mean with "Expected directory at URL at "testing.csv"?

Tags: swift, createml, mlmodel

I used CreateML to train mlmodels in the past and it has been working perfectly fine, but here is my problem: I am using training and testing data with 11 labels. When adding the files, the CreateML starts. Once it gets to the evaluation stage, it stops with an error saying: "Expected directory at URL at "testing.csv"
What directory is missing? I tried creating 11 directories at this location named after the labels, but that doesn't help. There is just 1 post about this issue at the Apple developer forum (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/676500), but this solution is not working for me. I also can't do it using playground, as I will get an unknown internal error.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this! [Apple Developer Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZRCf.png)

I hava the same Problem. I think like this, you should organize you data in folder

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30927370)